# .htaccess doesn't redirect direct link to .php files

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex requestHandler.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ requestHandler.php?/$0 [L,QSA]
```

I want to redirect alle requests to "requestHandler.php". It works now, but it is also possible to access sites with the direct link, and I don't want that.

For example:
It now works with ".../api/register" , but you can also access it but going to ".../register.php" and that shouldn't be possible. It should only be possible to go to register.php by ".../api/register".

I think I had it working before, but as I continued editing I've seemed to mess it up.

requestHandler.php should be working properly and when I enter ".../register.php" it is not at all redirected to requestHandler, but if I enter ".../registe.php" or ".../register.ph" it is redirected there.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule you posted is only checking if the file/directory exists, and if it doesn't, then redirect to requestHandler.php. So naturally, if an existing file is entered in the URL, it will not redirect.

If you want all ".php" files to get redirected as well, you'll need a more specific Rewrite rules. Something like this maybe:

```
DirectoryIndex requestHandler.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ requestHandler.php?/$0 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ requestHandler.php?/$0 [L,QSA]
```

You can probably consolidate that into one rule block, but at least this way it's very readable. The second rule block is only checked if the requested file is not a file or a directory.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. I desided to move my whole project into a subfolder and had some problem making it working there too, but I figured it out. So for you who wants to know how it's done in a subfolder use: `RewriteBase /subfolder/`       NOT     `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/requestHandler.php?/$0 [L,QSA]`